# Interviewing for a grad role at a company you already interned for

Tags: interviewing, internship, reinterviewing

I was offered at grad position at a company I interned for 2 summers ago, but due to the fact I decided to take a year and do some research a university in the US, for this reason I had to turn down the offer but I told all this to the company and I said I would love to work when I come back.

I now have a interview for that company and they said I just have to come in for 1 interview due to the fact it has been a year.

My question is what kind of questions should I expect, also what type of question should I ask the interviewers at the end. Normally I ask questions like what your day like, and best thing about this company.

P.S. Also my interviewers are people I already met and have socialised with over drinks during the internship.

Comment: Have you asked HR what format the interview is

Comment: Sorry, yes they said competency based with some technical and my motivation around the role. (Tech role)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is what kind of questions should I expect?

This is interview will mostly(remember mostly depending on the Manager and Interviewers) be a formality since they know that you have already worked with them.

They would like to ask you some technical questions to make sure you have not lost out on some skills you developed when you worked for them.

One good way to prepare for such interviews is to ask for the job description just mentioning you would love to prepare beforehand for the interview. They will be impressed to know this.

> also what type of question should I ask the interviewers at the end.

You could ask questions like:
1. Which project are you working on currently?
2. How different is it from the previous project(the project you worked on during intership)?
3. When do you they need you to start?

Good Luck for your Interview!

Comment: +1 This interview does sound like a formality if you have worked with the interviewers before.